# Does Redis FUNCTION LOAD participate in transactions?

Tags: redis

I'm using REDIS FUNCTION LOAD to load functions into a Redis where persistence is turned off. That is, if this Redis dies, a new one is started with a blank slate. I'm running Redis 7.0.11 in a container, and talking to it using go-redis version 8.11.5

I want to make the clients reload the function library if they detect it's not loaded.
However, I may have multiple versions of clients, and I want the latest version of the library to prevail.

So, what I want to do is, in pseudo-code:

```
WATCH version
MULTI
GET version
if version < my_version (or nil):
    FUNCTION LOAD REPLACE code
    SET version my_version
EXEC
```

Reading the documentation, it doesn't talk about FUNCTION LOAD in the context of transactions, but it also doesn't really talk about transactions for other commands, just separately in WATCH/EXEC, so by this reading, I assume FUNCTION LOAD will actually be transactional like the other mutations.

Does anyone have experience to the contrary, or a reference to some documentation I may have missed?